# Can a proxy (w/o cache) increase internet connection?

Tags: proxy

I got a server in Germany and people from America report a slow connection to the server. A local server in America which caches content would increase the connection speed.
But I wonder if a server in America which just acts as a proxy (without a cache since the content is dynamic) to the one in Germany can increase the bandwidth to Americans or will it just use the same slow hops like the ones Americans use when they directly connect to the German server?

Comment: I bought a small VPS in America and let the user test the server. They report max speed to the American one and 100-200kb/s to the German one. But I can download/Upload files from America to Germany with full 100mbit/s!

Answer (score 1):

The path might technically be different for the proxy and for a non-proxied client, but in practice they are going to negotiate the same set of paths and so the packet journeys will be equivalent. That said, although the sites may be dynamic, very often some of the largest parts of the web site (such as image files, even small ones) will in reality be static (since even dynamic sites use templates for formatting, etc.) and therefore susceptible to speed gains via intelligent caching.

Comment: In fact the main part of our application is not HTTP. So not cacheable. That means that it most likely will not increase the speed?